# Calling GET/POST requests using JMeter API

Tags: jmeter

have a requirement where i need to call get/post/put requests using Jmeter APIs.can some one suggest how to call get, post requests from JSR 223/beanshell/java sampler?

Trying with below code. but i am not expert with JMeter API.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.*    
HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
httpSampler.sample("http://example.com", "GET", true, 0);
```

Comment: is there any issue that you are facing in particular ? Is there any reason to not use Http sampler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **really** need to do it via [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), here is an example [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) code (it uses [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/), see [QuickStart](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/quickstart.html) for more examples)

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://10.195.78.185")
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get)

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity()
byte [] responseData = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity)
def statusCode = response.getStatusLine().statusCode
if (statusCode >= 400) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
}
SampleResult.setResponseCode(statusCode as String)
SampleResult.setResponseMessage(response.getStatusLine().reasonPhrase)
SampleResult.setResponseData(responseData)
```

---

However I would recommend not to reinvent the wheel and use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers. In conjunction with [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) you can use it for load testing of any HTTP-based API and JMeter will automatically take care about collecting metrics like latency, idle time, connect time, handling response codes, etc. See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks alot Dmitri. Now, i got your point. In the results .csv file, i see JSR223 sampler information. but, need to log GET call metrics information.

Comment: like what? You have `SampleResult` shorthand where you can populate all the required metrics, however you will need to calculate them yourself

Comment: i am testing an application where each page consists of REST calls ( some are repetitive) and navigation sequence of pages by different customers would be different.  hence, pages random navigation logic developed with java and imported as jar file. i want to put above suggested code in a method and relevant info like URL, Headers,POST body (for POST requests) will be sent as arguments. in such case, does SampleResult still collects metrics for REST calls exclusively and report in .jtl file? please don't mind for the silly question. It's indeed an important one for me.

Comment: When it comes to scripting you need to handle headers, cookies, variables, etc. manually, `SampleResult` will automatically record only its start and end times. You might also find [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) article interesting.